# Rename files in a folder using powershell, keeping the start and end of string in original filename

Tags: powershell, rename

Currently trying to create a script that renames specific files within a chosen folder so that the resulting renamed files look like the following:

- Original Filename: `45.09 - WrapperA12_rev1.DXF`
- Resultant Filename: `45.09_1.DXF`

So the rev number is included as a suffix to the base filename, the extension is kept and the first 5 characters of the filename is kept (including the ".").

I can get fairly close by removing the hyphens, spaces and letters from the original filename using the -replace argument, but the resultant filename using the example above would be "45.0912_1", where the file extension is ".0912_1". This makes sense, but any attempt I've made to append the file extension (".DXF") to the filename hasn't worked.

```
$listdxf=gci -path $pathfolder -Filter *.DXF | Select-Object
$prenameDXF=$listdxf|rename-item -WhatIf -newname {$_.name -replace('[a-z]') -replace('-') - 
replace('\s','')}
$prenameDXF
```

Any feedback on how I would go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.

For further clarification; the original filenames will always have the 4 numbers and the dot at the start of the filename - these need to be kept for the output name, the only other number I want is the number at the end of the filename that will always refer to the revision number, however this number may be variable (i.e; it could be 0 or 0.1,1,1.1 etc.). The Rev number will ALWAYS follow the underscore in the original filename. All other numbers and letters etc. in the original filename need to be removed. I'm assuming the solution might include assigning a variable to just return the first 4 numbers (i.e; XX.XX) as a substring maybe, while assigning a variable to the last few characters that follow the "_". Then maybe combine the two and add the ".DXF" file extension.

LATEST UPDATE: Following the responses here, I've been able to get the functionality nearly exactly where I need it to be.
I've been using the regex provided below, and with some slight changes adapted it to allow for some other things (to allow for spaces after "rev" and to allow for the rev number to be separated by a dot if present, i.e; rev1.1 etc.), but currently struggling to find a way of simply returning "0" if no "rev" is present in the file name. For example, if a filename is as follows: 31.90 - SADDLE SHIM.DXF - I wish for the rename regex script to return 31.90_0. The expression I'm currently using is as follows: `'(\d{2}\.\d{2}).*?rev(\s?\d+\.\d+|\s?\d+).*(?=\.DXF)', '$1_$2'`
I have tried putting a pipeline (if) after the capture block following the "rev" and then putting (0) in a new capture block, but that's not working. Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again for the replies.

Comment: is it always "the first 5 characters of the filename" or it's actually all digits including the dot? could be less or more

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added additional information to the OP. It will always be the first 4 numbers (including the dot), but the other number I want can vary in number of digits (i.e; 1,11,1.1 etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this regex could do the trick to rename your files with your desired format: [`(?<=\.\d+)\s.+(?=_rev)|rev`](https://regex101.com/r/shAgs7/1).

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *-*_rev*.dxf |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?<=\.\d+)\s.+(?=_rev)|rev' }
```

However the above assumes all files will start with some digits followed by a dot followed by more digits and may or may not be 5 digits including dots. It also assumes there will be a white space after the remaining digits. It also assumes the files will end with `rev` followed by more digits after it's `dxf` extension.

This regex could work too [`(?<=^[\d.]{5})\s.+(?=_rev)|rev`](https://regex101.com/r/kHuRj2/1), however this one assumes only will capture the first 5 digits including one or more dots.

Comment: THANKS!! This worked perfectly for the folder I tried it in, unfortunately some of the folders include an annoying file naming structure similar to the following: 30.05 - Shell- (21191-C1 rev0).DXF. I'm assuming there'd need to be additional conditions for the annoying brackets? Or maybe a way to simply remove the brackets entirely from the name? I have no idea what I'm looking at with these regex expressions tbh.

Comment: @Jesse,  `Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(\d{2}\.\d{2}).*?rev(\d+).*(?=\.DXF)', '$1_$2'}` should work

Answer (score 0):

Per your update, you could try using `switch` with the `-regex` option.  `$Matches` will contain the matches and you can reference the match groups by using the group number as the key (e.g. `$Matches[1]`).  You may also reference as a property (e.g., `$Matches.1`)

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\powershell\testrename -File | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { 
        switch -Regex ($_.Name) {
            '(\d{2}\.\d{2}).*?rev(\s?\d+\.\d+|\s?\d+).*(?=\.DXF)' {
                "$($Matches.1)_$($Matches.2).DXF"
                break
            }
            '(\d{2}\.\d{2}).*(?=\.DXF)' {
                "$($Matches.1)_0.DXF"
                break            
            }
            default {
                $_
            }
        }
    } -WhatIf
```

Remove `-WhatIf` once done testing to perform rename action